# Web API Azure .net c# request, visible to others, content of URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, url, azure-web-app-service

My question is, can someone see your full URL web API, that you developed when a user makes a request with that URL get/post/delete/put ? Can they see in network traffic your Web APIs URL that are being called?
Example of URL: https://webapiserver.azure.com/something/something/Username/password
Can you actually see these content when the request is being made from a user, lets say i am developing an Android application, and inside that application, i make these kind of API request, and i worrying about the security, if an 'attacker' can see the content..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can focus on these to secure your server connection.

All request URLs are visible to outside.
Never ever send passwords or any sensitive information through URLs.
URL can have insensitive parameters like pageno, sort-order etc..

> If you want to authenticate a user, Go for a POST request where
> username and password are inside the POST body. This alone won't
> secure you however.

Use

```
POST: http://yourapp.com/api/authenticate
BODY:
{
   "username": "admin",
   "password": "some_hashed_password"
}
```

Instead of

```
GET: http://yourapp.com/api/authenticate?username=admin&password=some_hashed_password
```

> Always use SSL to connect to API

You should always use SSL to secure your API.
SSL encrypts your request and response. Your URL will be still visible but payloads will be encrypted.

Comment: For SSL/TLS to work, do I need certificate to encrypt that?

Comment: Yes you need. You can get free SSL for your server from here https://letsencrypt.org/. Its a nonprofit Certificate Authority provider. You should have admin access to your server to configure SSL